# How do I check whether or not a variable is set in a FOR loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, scripting

I have this FOR loop:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=():/ " %%a in (svn.txt) DO (
```

While it explicitly calls for 5 `tokens` there may be only 3 or 4.

1. Is there a better way to code "tokens" to get the number of tokens in the line being parsed"
2. How do I tell if the third (for example) token has a value assigned to it? I've tried `IF NOT DEFINED` but with `tokens=1,2,3,4,5` apparently `%%c`, `%%d` and `%%e` are always defined even if their value is `%%c`, `%%d` and `%%e`. I can't figure out how to check whether these variables have their own name assigned or a real value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=():/ " %%a in (svn.txt) do (
    if "%%c"=="" echo third token does not contain data

)
```

Since you are requesting 5 tokens, they will be defined for all the iterations of the loop. They will hold a value or not depending of the tokenization of the line.

If none of the tokens get data when reading/parsing the line, the code in the `do` clause will not be executed for this line.

Answer (score 0):

Duh.  `if [%%e] EQU []`. I had this at one point but had other logic issues I was blaming on this.